# Image not showing in live hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I have used spatie media library package for uploading images in my laravel project . It was completely fine on localhost and it uploading and showing too . But in live server it is uploading but it is not showing . It kust show img icon and when I open it it says

> Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/RMC/public/../../rentmerooms/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/RMC/public/index.php on line 24

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/RMC/public/../../rentmerooms/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/RMC/public/index.php on line 24

but in database it is there ..

This is how I upload picture using spatie media library package

```
    $room = Room::create($request->all());
    $room->addMedia($request->display_image)->toMediaCollection();
    return redirect()->to('/rooms')->with('success','Room Created 
    Successfully');
```

this is how I am showing the image

```
@foreach($room->getMedia() as $media)
 <img src="{{ asset($media->getUrl('thumb') }}" style="max-width: 100%;">
@endforeach
```

Comment: take care what is directory permission and in sever file uploaded or not. if uploaded where is uploaded?

Comment: It is uploading files in storage/public

Comment: Do you check permission of directory?

Comment: Yes it is alright there

Comment: When you open link of image in browser what error do you see?

Comment: Site Can't be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Photo link comes this
http://localhost:8000/storage/29/conversions/IMG_6913-thumb.jpg

Comment: Does a symlink exist between `storage/app/public` and `public/storage` (see [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk))? Is the `APP_URL` set correctly in `.env`?

Comment: I did but nothings changed